# AngularJs, add directive attribute to scope without isolation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I created a `directive` which uses parent scope.
The `directive` should accept a attribute i.e

```
<my-nice-new-directive data-hide-icon="true" />
```

but I do not want to isolate scope. Is it possible to just add the attribute to the `$scope`?

Comment: Why don't you want an isolate scope?

Comment: its a more complex directive, i just simplified it for the question in here. But yes, idealy i should refactor it. But you know how this works in companies. No budget for refactoring :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider having fun with the [`$parse`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) service.

```
.directive('myNiceNewDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        controller: function ($scope, $attrs, $parse) {
            var hideIcon = $parse($attrs.hideIcon)($scope);
        }
    };
})
```

or you could just evaluate the variable `data-hide-icon="{{isIconHidden}}"`, in which case you may want to watch it.

```
.directive('myNiceNewDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: true, //this is not necessary but could be useful
        controller: function ($scope, $attrs) {
            $scope.$watch(function () {return $attrs.hideIcon;}, function (newValue, oldValue) {
               //react to change...
            });
        }
    };
})
```